# Strange chrome behavior in RTL with parentheses

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, right-to-left

I don't know if that is a bug or a feature or if it could be fixed easily until Chrome will fix that.

```css
div {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-US" dir="rtl">
  <body>
    <div>test1 (12)</div>
    <div>test1 (12) &nbsp;</div>
    <div>test1 (12) test2</div>
    <div>test1 (t)</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's what I see:

[image]

Chrome Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit) (Windows 10)

Comment: I can reproduce the error in Chrome v73. But Chrome v75 (the canary) already behaves like the other browsers do, so the fix will likely come to the regular Chrome soon.

Comment: It is still an issue in Chrome 76 (on Windows 10). Not an issue in Firefox or Edge. I am using CSS `direction: rtl`, FWIW. It happens with other characters too, so not just with the bracket.

Comment: It's been reported to Chrome team but not fixed: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=968884

Comment: Woah! Now I even see the same issue with LTR spans. I have updated the bug accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has to do with how google Chrome parses special characters for RTL languages

```
const label = 'طالب(ة)'
const openingTag = '\u202B(';
const closingTag = ')\u202C';
const computedLabel = label.replace(/\)/g, closingTag).replace(/\(/g, openingTag);
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be fixed with the current (111) version of Chrome.